# Should "I'm not a native English speaker" lines be removed?

Tags: discussion, edits, non-english-speakers, languages

Sometimes I see questions with unnecessary "*Hello to you from Username!*", which obviously doesn't contribute or help understand the problem in any way. But I'm not sure about cases where people say "*Sorry for my bad English*" and such. These kind of warn the reader that the OP might have used wrong terms without knowing, so it sort of helps to guess what the problem is, if it's not clear enough.

Should these be removed?

Comment: I'd say - if you can't fix language in post, either leave them be until someone who can will see this, or move them to comments. And this does not really apply to "English language" site at all ;) there the status of native speaker can have some meaning (especially when discussing colloquial speech).

Comment: I would move that line to a comment if I could, actually, but I guess that requires a lot of rep or even mod privileges.

Comment: Many times people with *good English* make this remark (!).

Comment: @brasofilo I was about to say the exact same thing! When I edit those, I sometimes put in the edit description, "Your english is just fine!"

Comment: user1306322 I meant simply writing your comment saying you edited this out. @brasofilo OK, now I'm surprised. I only ever note it (in comment!) if I'm unsure if my English was good enough, and don't quite understand why someone who can be confident ever posts it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber, exactly, me too!

Comment: This is a perfect use case for a comment below the question.  Comments are for clarification, and making note that the OP is a non-native speaker is a clarification.

Comment: @RobinGreen yes, it is.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you at the same time address any problems with the question, such as any mistakes a non-native speaker might have made, go ahead and remove it.

Comment: Well, here's the thing − sometimes I'm not knowledgeable enough in the area of the question, so I might not be able to recognize erroneously used terminology. But if I remove that line and someone else comes along, wouldn't my edit impair their ability to identify the problem? Should I just leave it to the discretion of the users knowledgeable in the area?

Comment: You can only fix what you recognize as wrong. So if you feel the question is otherwise clear and fine, feel free to remove that statement. If you are unclear on the overall question however, and don't know how to edit it other than that one line, perhaps leave it to others.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, they should be taken out.

Preferably while fixing grammar and spelling...

These are **noise** - they are not relevant to the question.